# Can I use the Vista speech API in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: speech-recognition

I have writtena small app on the iphone that transfers 30 seconds of speech to a webserver that calls a windows service via remoting, the service uses SAPI5.1 on windows 2003 server to convert the wave to text via the defuault recognizer.

I want to update the engine to the latest and add a medical speech model that was created to run in Vista.  Can I do this via windows 2003 server and an app writen in .net 3.5 libraries.  Does Vista just use the 3.5 .net libs anyway.  Can I change the speech modiel via a registry  or api call, I know that ot use the speech models on vista yo have to cahange a registry key under speech recog,

Any ideas?
Thanks,Tom

Comment: I changed the title to something more closely resembling the question. It was "Hi Phillip."

Comment: There's a Phillip in my office, he works in accounting but I'll see if he wants to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is no, you need to stick with sappi 5.1 If you upgraded to server 2008 you could probably make use of vista specific speach recognission features. YOu should be able to use the sappi application programming interface in ..net 3.5 I know it can be used with the .net 3.0 framework. For more information on the different sdk's available see this link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Application_Programming_Interface

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft makes a server recognizer available for a free download. See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4

See [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec/2998963#2998963) for more information.