# Why does my Microsoft Speech recognition results come with confidence levels always equal to -1?

Tags: speech-recognition

I am using the Microsoft Speech SDK to implement a software using voice recognition.

I feed the recognition engine with a quite normal grammar, but when starting the engine and saying something correct, it recognizes what i say but the returned Result object has a Confidence value of -1.

Besides, all SemanticValue objects contained in the result also have a -1 confidence.

I cannot find a trace of the meaning of such a result in the related MSDN pages, and actually it is just written that typical confidence values should be between 0 and 1.

What does a -1 value mean ? Does it have something to do with the grammar?

Edit : Additional infos :

- I am using the System.Speech classes to interact with the voice recognition engine.
- The recognition engine is Microsoft English Recognizer v5.1.
- I am running the program on XP and thus the Speech SDK is also 5.1.
- The input is a microphone input: I did not find trace of the possibility to feed this recognition engine with a file, although it would have helped me a lot.

Comment: You might want to clarify some things. Are you using SAPI or System.Speech or Microsoft.Speech? What OS version are you running on? What recognizer version are you running? Are you using a shared or inproc recognizer? how was your grammar created? Are you using microphone input or wav file? I don't know what the problem is, but some more information may help you get some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SAPI the SREngineConfidence is an attempt to pass the phrase confidence from the vendor specific speech engine to the engine independent SAPI client. SREngineConfidence has some interesting behavior described in "Microsoft Speech SDK Version 5.1 SR Engine Vendor Porting Guide"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431799(v=VS.85).aspx#_Toc503606917 says:

> It is possible for confidence score
>   information to be included in
>   recognition results. On each phrase
>   element there are two confidence
>   fields that the engine can set. These
>   have both a Confidence (three-level)
>   field and an SREngineConfidence
>   (floating-point) field. If the engine
>   does not explicitly set any of these
>   values, SAPI will try and produce
>   reasonable default values for them. It
>   will produce the Confidence values by
>   averaging the levels for each of the
>   words in the phrase or property, and
>   **it will set the SREngineConfidence
>   values to -1.0.**

and later says:

> **If this field is not being used, the
>   engine sets this confidence to -1.0.**

One other resource that may give you some insight is http://gotspeech.net/forums/thread/3613.aspx. One post says:

> In principle, the SREngineConfidence
>   score is a value between 0.0 and 1.0
>   {higher value meaning higher
>   confidence}. But older versions of the
>   SR engines like 5.1 don't honor this
>   contract precisely, and I don't think
>   the value can really be used with
>   those engines. Only the Hi, Medium,
>   and Low scores in the other Confidence
>   field are usable.
>
> If I remember rightly, you need a more
>   recent version of the SR engine, like
>   the versions that ship with Microsoft
>   Office 2003 or Vista to get a
>   meaningful number in the
>   SREngineConfidence field.

Edits:

I believe System.Speech.Recognition is really a .net wrapper around SAPI (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx). I suspect that the comments quoted above that describe confidence levels of -1 may still apply to you using System.Speech. I'm guessing that the -1 you are seeing is the same issue mentioned.

My understanding is that XP did not include a recognizer. Versions of Microsoft Office came with it. So, I'm not sure which recognizer engine you are really running. Do you have Office 2003 installed? or do you have a 3rd party engine like Dragon installed?

You say you have recognizer 5.1 installed. The GotSpeech.NET link above says:

> But older versions of the SR engines
>   like 5.1 don't honor this contract
>   precisely, and I don't think the value
>   can really be used with those engines.

I would suggest trying the following:

- Test the same code on a newer machine, perhaps Vista or Windows 7 and see if the Condifence levels work properly. Vista and later include the recognizer engine.
- Try installing a newer version of the recognizer. You could install UCMA or http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb0f72cb-b86b-46d1-bf06-665895a313c7. Note that these use the namespace Microsoft.Speech and not System.Speech. See [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec)

One more piece to add. Here is a short sample to recognize from a wav file:

```
    SpeechRecognitionEngine myRecognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    Grammar myGrammar = CreatePizzaGrammar();       // uses GrammarBuilder to create a pizza ordering grammar
    myRecognizer.LoadGrammar(myGrammar);
    myRecognizer.SetInputToWaveFile("LargeCheese.wav");     // recording of ordering a pizza
    RecognitionResult result = myRecognizer.Recognize();
    string s = result.Text;
    float confidence = result.Confidence;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your answer. However I am not using SAPI. I am using System.Speech. I updated the answer to provide the detailed information you were asking for.

Comment: To run the recongnizer with a wav file input, use SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Oh my god you are my genius.. I searched for this for so long !!

Comment: My problem is not resolved but your showing me `SetInputToWaveFile()` is as worthy to me. Yet if you have an idea to solve the problem with my current System.Speech classes, I will be glad to hear from you!

Comment: Try a newer version of the recognizer. I bet your code will work properly and you are just seeing a SAPI artifact from an old recognizer. That is my guess.