# Detect sound boundaries in an audio file

Tags: python, opencv, audio

I have an audio file I want to split into multiple files.  The files are structured into pairs of sound separated by silence.  The timeline looks like this with - to represent silence:

-----Sound A1-----Sound A2-----Sound B1-----Sound B2-----

I want to find the boundary between Sound A2 and Sound B1.  I want a solution preferably using a combination of Python, OpenCV, and FFmpeg, but any tools that work will do.

Comment: I don't think OpenCV is appropriate here. You may want to consider [alternatives](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/912/is-there-an-analogous-library-to-opencv-for-audio-analysis).See also [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/simplest-way-of-detecting-where-audio-envelopes-start-and-stop) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758485/open-source-code-for-voice-detection-and-discrimination)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Miki for the links.  [Aubio](http://aubio.org/) is a tool that works perfectly.  The program aubioquiet will detect silence boundaries and print their timestamps:

`$ aubioquiet temp.wav 
NOISY: 0.638549
QUIET: 2.008526
NOISY: 4.992290
QUIET: 6.286803
NOISY: 9.258957
QUIET: 10.559275
NOISY: 13.531428
QUIET: 14.622766
NOISY: 17.623945
QUIET: 18.953287
NOISY: 21.931248
QUIET: 23.260590
NOISY: 26.238548
QUIET: 27.643356
NOISY: 30.632925
QUIET: 31.915827
NOISY: 34.882175
QUIET: 36.165081`