# Google Speech Recognition API on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-api, speech-recognition

i am trying to use the Google APIS in developing a Windows Phone application, i am specifically interested in the speech recognition API from Google but i want to know if it is available for windows phone developers, if it is, i need more details please

Comment: I searched your tags on google, and the first two responses http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/96999/578944.aspx and http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2875352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Speech API, i guess you mean the Speech API which is used by google in Android phones is not written in C#. Therefore, the answer to your question is no - currently it's not available.

Have a look at this stackoverflow post, there was already a discussion about good Speech APIs in .NET:
[good Speech recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467827/good-speech-recognition-api)

greetings