# System.Speech to recognize letters and numbers instead of words or sentences

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

I am attempting to get basic recognition of letters and numbers with System.Speech rather than words or sentences. I am using the code sample from the top answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467827/good-speech-recognition-api). Here are some of the odd results I am seeing:

```
(spoken, recognized)
ABC123, BB sheet 123
7N2591, It had been 2591
374SXQ, Greet heaven or dashes at queue
51763, Hide one chat and had three
XYZ709, At YE having your own nine
```

Are there different grammar sets, or an approach with the GrammarBuilder that would allow me to limit recognition to only listen for a series of letters and numbers?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?