# Voice recognition in .net. Sphinx, ISIP, Julius

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to implement a voice recognition feature in my application written in c#. System.Speech.Recognition is not suitable, because the number of languages it supports is not enough.

I have found several engines, but they aren't written in .net and I can't find any wrappers. So, which one to use: Sphinx, ISIP, Julius? Do you know any .net wrappers for them? Do you know any tutorials or articles that can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do you require a dictation grammar? What languages are missing? What versions of Windows must this run on?

I don't know all of the languages supported by System.Speech under Windows 7, but these links look helpful

- Windows 7 speech Recognition, Language selection - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-speech-recognition-language-selection/0a859099-a76d-4799-abe9-847997399927
- Windows 7 language packs - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813/

If you don't need a dictation grammar, you can try Microsoft.Speech and the server recognizers. there are 26 languages supported:

- Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime Languages (Version 10.2) - 
  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47FFD4E5-E682-4228-8058-DD895252A3C3

See [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec) which may have some helpful background.