# Voice command, Speech Recognition using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am trying to write a C# application using Windows Phone.make the user give a speech command to open the camera for example,,looking for references that would help.
Regards

Comment: My bad,it's a Windows Phone Application,want to utilize(camera, for example) to make it Open under my Speech Command.Is that possible?;if it is,i want references,Regards.

Comment: Updates:: i found this http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/05/12/windows-phone-7-prototype-001-speech-recognition-on-wp7/ ,,now, i need to know if i can convert the result to command line make the Camera Open,,Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To get started with .NET speech, there is a very good article that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far. It is a little out of date, but very helfpul. (The AppendResultKeyValue method was dropped after the beta.)

A good starting point in the official documentation is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361625.aspx

There are lots of good posts on StackOverflow. See 
[What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737003/90236 for some starter links.

Comment: I appreciate your help, actually the introductory article was valuable ;right now, i'm falling deep in the official documentation; if anything happened,i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5820/Speech-Recognition

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ssrinivas/SpeeechRecognitionusingCSharp11222005054918AM/SpeeechRecognitionusingCSharp.aspx