# I am using a Android platform to create C# in C# shell app,trying to make a TTS project but It shows an error platform not supported what should I do?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, platform

I am using a Android platform to create C# in C# shell app, trying to make a TTS project but It shows an error platform not supported what should I do?

This is the full error showing in the compiler:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Speech is not supported on this platform.
  at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer..ctor () [0x0000b] in <c034596bb13941d595cd8320f8daa0bf>:0 
  at HI.Hi.Main () [0x00000] in <8252de4446134ebc80800bd83a60b532>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <fed255019475411fbbf36266714e0878>:0
```

and I do not know what to do now ? Please Help me....

I do not know what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PlatformNotSupportedException Using .NET Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741053/platformnotsupportedexception-using-net-speech-recognition)

Comment: Yes, you are trying to run the windows specific library on android. Try [Android.Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/speech) instead.