# Microsoft Kinect Speech DLL missing from installed path. Where can I find the Speech.dll for the same?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am writing a application to recognize and parse speech captured by Microsoft Kinect.

I do have the Kinect SDK installed, but I am unable to capture any voice data on Kinect as the Speech dll is missing.

I did check the installation path, but I do not find any folder named `Speech` under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\`. The Kinect SDK version I have installed is 2.0.

Could you please tell me where I can find the missing DLLs?

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Speech Recognition - what reference do I have to add?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002591/microsoft-speech-recognition-what-reference-do-i-have-to-add)

Comment: Possible duplicate - check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002591/microsoft-speech-recognition-what-reference-do-i-have-to-add

Comment: Also check this ones: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Hello-Kinect-Kinect-v2-Speech-Recognition-example https://elbruno.com/2014/07/03/kinectsdk-speech-recognition-now-available-in-sdk-v2/  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855387.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Speech Runtime installed. It's advised to use the x86 version of the runtime. You can find the runtime by looking under "Components" tab in the SDK Browser or by going to this [page](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=404115).

I also highly recommend you to take a look at the Speech example in the SDK Browser