# Matching wildcard/dictation in Microsoft Speech Grammar

Tags: grammar, speech, microsoft-speech-api

I'm using Microsoft Speech API to load a grxml grammar:

```
Grammar grammar = new Grammar(file);
grammar.Enabled = true;

SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = GetEngine();
sre.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
```

Based on MSDN I can not find tag to match a wildcard / spoken text like:

```
<item>My message is {dictation}</item>
```

It seems to be availalble with code with a DictationGrammar and appendDictation(). It's also available with WSRMacro XML using * but I do not how to do it in XML ?

The  skip text but I need to recognize it.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Kinect speech engine, you cannot use dictation at all; the engine simply doesn't support it.

For more details, you can look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re/2982910#2982910).

Comment: But in the C# API there is a DictationGrammar and WildcardGrammar. I could archive my goal if I "harcode" it. In fact I activate a Dictation grammar for som special case (even if it is bad I agree)

Comment: The C# API works with both the desktop engine *and* the server engine.  The desktop engine supports DictationGrammar and WildcardGrammar; the server engine does not.

Comment: Kinect uses Microsoft.Speech, not System.Speech as it seems, although you could probably grab the audio from Kinect and use it with System.Speech somehow (but I think you need training of the recognition engine if you go with System.Speech)

Comment: Btw, it seems Microsoft united their previously separate installers for their Server (accessed via Microsoft.Speech in .NET) and Client (accessed via System.Speech in .NET) Speech Runtimes into Microsoft Speech Platform Runtime (Version 11), found at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225. The respective SDK is at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226. The speech runtime version that was labeled in the past "for servers" is non-trainable (has setting for acoustic model adaptation on/off though) and doesn't accept free speech, only commands

Answer (score 0):

For my project [SARAH](http://encausse.wordpress.com/s-a-r-a-h)

- I load all XML grammar
- Then I create a dictation grammar
- Some user's action enable/disable the dictation mode

I know there should be a better way to do it since [WSRMacro](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13045) use '*' but I don"t know how to do it.

Might be [a clue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.appendwildcard.aspx)