# Is there a .NET 2.0 Version of System.Speech.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I would like to know if there is a .NET 2.0 Version of System.Speech.dll

I have a bunch of `dlls` in my project targeting .NET 2.0 and i noticed a project referencing `System.Speech.dll`; I tried finding on Google if there was any in `.Net 2.0` but couldn't figure out, following is the code how i figured the .NET versions of the dlls in a directory.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDotNetVersion()
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path to all dlls"))
        {
            Assembly assembly = null;
            string version = null;
            try
            {
                assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file);
                version = assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Which are all .NET v2.0.50727
When i used .NET Reflector I figured a dll referring to System.Speech.dll.
Can a .NET 2.0 dll refer to dlls that were targeted to 3.0 or 3.5 or 4 Versions of .NET? (to my knowledge i do know it can't be)
If no where can I find .NET 2.0 Version of System.Speech.dll?

Thanks!

Comment: I must go with what we have and build upon it, Whats a taser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure System.Speech was introduced in .Net 3.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition(v=vs.85).aspx. It really made its first appearance in Windows Vista - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.asp.

Don't forget, if you are targeting older systems, you must have a recognition engine installed. XP and Server OSes don't have recognition engine installed by default. This might be helpful - [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re/2998963#2998963)