# Change the language of Speech Recognition Engine library

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

I am working on a program (in C#) to recognize voice commands from the user and execute in the PC, i.e. the user says "start menu" and the PC opens the start menu.

I have find a cool library: [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) for the speech recognition, the problem is that I need to recognize spanish language too, is there any way to change the language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [SpeechRecognitionEngine(CultureInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) overload.

```
var speechRec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("es-ES")));
```

This assumes that the user has the Spanish culture installed, otherwise an `ArgumentException` will be thrown. The `SpeechRecognitionEngine` class implements `IDisposable`, so it's a good idea to call `speechRec.Dispose()` when you're done, or use it in a `using` statement.

Comment: what is "Spanish culture" do you mean the windows is in spanish?

Comment: Yes, the user needs to have the Spanish speech recognizer installed. If you buy a Windows PC in Spain, I'm guessing this is installed as standard but I don't have the Spanish one on my PC (in the UK) so if I was to run that code, I'd get an exception. I believe Windows 7 Ultimate users can download additional language packs. If you don't specify a culture, it will use the default one installed on the user's machine.

Comment: oooh, i got it, thank you man! btw is there any other way to recognize voice in c#?

Comment: No problem. There are other third party libraries, but the SpeechRecognitionEngine is from Microsoft and is actually quite good IMHO. I'm using it in my current project. You can use `System.Speech` or `Microsoft.Speech` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re). Both have pros and cons.

Comment: If your windows 10 (or higher) comes in, say, English. You can add more languages by typing "Add a language to this device", when downloading the new language, make sure you check the "Speech" option to have the speech recognizer downloaded.