# SpeechRec Program in Greek Language

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Im trying to make a speech recognition program that can recognize Greek and do whatever the user commands it to do, such as "Close window" , "Open this" etc (but in the Greek language). However, i cant seem to find a solution for that matter. From what i've searched theres no Greek language in VS but i was wondering if theres any way i could probably add it , like a package or something. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe this link could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981294/change-the-language-of-speech-recognition-engine-library

Comment: This is what i tried, didnt work                                                                   `var Greek = new CultureInfo(("el-GR"));
          
           var speechRec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(Greek);`