# Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis does not work for Text To Speech BUT System.Speech.Synthesis works.Why?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, sapi, speech-synthesis

I just try to run simple microsoft example for Text To Speech using using **Microsoft.Speech.dll;**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace TTS
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing TTS!");

            // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
            using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
            {

                // Output information about all of the installed voices.
                Console.WriteLine("Installed voices -");
                foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
                {
                    VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;
                    Console.WriteLine(" Voice Name: " + info.Name);
                }

                // Select the US English voice.
                synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-GB, Hazel)");

                // Build a prompt.
                PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
                builder.AppendText("That is a big pizza!");

                // Speak the prompt.
                synth.Speak(builder);
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Although I have the right voices, **it does not make any sound**. No  Text To Speech(TTS) voice.

[image]

When I use Microsoft **System.Speech.dll** then **I can hear voice**. So there is no sound problem.

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace TTS
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing TTS!");

            // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
            using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
            {

                // Output information about all of the installed voices.
                Console.WriteLine("Installed voices -");
                foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
                {
                    VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;
                    Console.WriteLine(" Voice Name: " + info.Name);
                }

                // Build a prompt.
                PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
                builder.AppendText("That is a big pizza!");

                // Speak the prompt.
                synth.Speak(builder);
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Shortly

> Why I can not hear any voice or make Text To Speech(TTS) with
>   Microsoft Speech Platform using Microsoft.Speech? Should I do some
>   extra config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using two different TTS engines.  Microsoft.Speech uses the server TTS voices; System.Speech uses the desktop TTS voices.  See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re/2982910#2982910).

Windows Vista and above have desktop TTS voices registered by default, but no server TTS voices.  When you install the [Server Speech Platform Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226), which I believe you have to do in order to get the Microsoft.Speech.dll loaded in the first place, you should have the option to install some server TTS voices as well.

Comment: I installed the server tts voices...And My Microsoft.Speech test program list them. I see the intalled voices and check them at windows registry.

Comment: Have you called [SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtodefaultaudiodevice(v=office.13).aspx)?  This doesn't happen by default with the Microsoft.Speech engine, while it does with the System.Speech engine.

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio Select Project, then select Add References, Then select the checkbox next to System.Speech

In your program do a using system.speech as well.

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you asked:

> Why I can not hear any voice or make Text To Speech(TTS) with Microsoft Speech Platform using Microsoft.Speech?

You are missing an important thing in your code. You cannot hear a voice because following line is missing:

```
synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
```

This allows you to hear the voice. I had the same problem. I modified your code an inserted the code sample above:

```
using System;

using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
 class Program
   {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Testing TTS!");

     // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
     using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
     {
        // Configure the synthesizer to send output to the default audio device.
        synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Output information about all of the installed voices.
        Console.WriteLine("Installed voices -");
        foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
        {
           VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;
           Console.WriteLine(" Voice Name: " + info.Name);
        }

        // Select the US English voice.
        synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-GB, Hazel)");

        // Speak.
        synth.Speak("That is a big pizza!");
     }

     Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
     Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
 }
}
```

Notice that the SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice is not necessary when you use the System.Speech.dll. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtodefaultaudiodevice?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the documentation about the method.