# SAPI acquiring different language recognisers

Tags: c#, c++, sapi

On my Windows 7 computer, I currently have the "Microsoft Windows Speech Recogniser 8.0 for Windows (English - UK)" and the "Microsoft Windows Speech Recogniser 8.0 for Windows (English - US)". I am wanting to develop an application the recognises French, Spanish and German, as well as English.

I have been searching for ages, but am unable to find the appropriate recognisers to download - could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Hnefatl

Edit: Don't worry, found a link: "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't the recognizers you're expecting.  The link you have is for server recognizers, while the recognizers you already have installed are for desktop recognizers.  (The differences between desktop recognizers and server recognizers are outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re/2982910#2982910).)

The Desktop recognizers are installed as part of the [Windows 7 Language Packs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/language-packs).

That being said, however, you cannot connect multiple recognizers to the same audio source and have the English recognizer send events for English speech and the French recognizer for French speech.  Rather, the English recognizer will analyze the incoming (French) audio and attempt to process it as if it were English, usually resulting in a bunch of incorrect recognitions.  The same is true for other languages.

Comment: Great, thank you - I was having trouble installing the server recognisers.