# Microsoft Speech Platform - sampling rate and bit depth

Tags: speech-recognition, sampling, wave, microsoft-speech-platform

Recognition results are best if sampling rate and bit depth of the audio match the training data of the system.

So, does anyone know the exact sampling rate and/or bit depth (and/or stereo/mono) that is used in Microsoft Speech Platform (newest, if that's important)? And if so, do you remember where you got this information?

Please note that I am using the MS Speech Platform, not the SAPI. Unless both are using the same training data, that's not the same AFAIK. To be precise - I use this: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile%28v=office.14%29.aspx

My first try is based upon the C++ code example given on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft.Speech SR engine doesn't need training ([unlike the System.Speech SR engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re/2982910#2982910)), and is relatively insensitive to sampling rate (will work with anything > 8 KHz sampling rate).  16 bit audio is preferred, but I *believe* that it will work with 8 bit audio.

Comment: It may work with practically everything, but from what I know speech recognition systems work best when used with the same sample rate/bit depth they had for training. To clarify: I don't intend to train the system, I try to decide on the optimal format of the material that's to be recognized.

Comment: Microsoft.Speech is built on top of 8 KHz 16 bit audio.  That being said, Microsoft.Speech is pretty insensitive to audio quality.

Comment: We run some tests on sample material - it seems the optimal setup for our purposes is 16 kHz 16 bit. This surprises me a bit. How do you know what MS SAPI is built on? I did not find that information anywhere. Can you give a link?

Comment: Oops. Yeah, that explains. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information regarding sample rate, but it seems the bit depth is actually 8-bit (maybe this has changed since [Eric Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164064/8856893)).

Quoted from [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/speechplatform_spstreamformat.aspx) listing supported audio formats:

> The Speech Platform downsamples audio that is of greater than 8-bit
>   resolution.

You should be fine providing any bit-depth which is a multiple of 8-bits (which is always the case anyway), since there will be no precision loss due to rounding (and there is no aliasing for resolution, unlike sample rate).