# How to use Microsoft Speech SDK 11 Language pack?

Tags: text-to-speech, language-packs, microsoft-speech-platform

I would like to use the MS Speech SDK 11 with different voices not only Microsoft Anna. I downloaded the language pack and installed some of them but they are not yet available.
How can I use different languages ​​with MS Speech SDK 11, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MS Speech SDK installs *server* TTS engines and *server* voices, and you need to use the `Microsoft.Speech` namespace to access these voices.  Microsoft Anna is a *desktop* voice, which uses the `System.Speech` namespace.  I explain the differences in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re/2982910#2982910).