# How to train Microsoft.Speech.Recognition engine

Tags: .net, speech-recognition

It almost all the time can't distinguish "man" from "men". I guess it's because of my pronunciation. When I use the sounds from online dictionaries, it usually works with over 90% confidence! but with my voice, nope!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982910/177018), Microsoft.Speech.Recognition uses the Server version of SAPI, which is designed for use with low-quality audio for command and control only, **not** dictation, and as such it sounds like it you cannot train it.

You could instead try training yourself:

From [Microsoft Windows website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/set-speech-recognition#1TC=windows-7):

> Windows comes with a speech training tutorial to help teach you the
>   commands used with Speech Recognition. The tutorial takes about 30
>   minutes to complete. Follow the steps below to run the speech training
>   tutorial:
>
> 1. Open Speech Recognition by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>      Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Ease of Access, and
>      then clicking Speech Recognition.
> 2. Click Take Speech Tutorial.
> 3. Follow the instructions in the Speech Recognition tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for System.Speech.Recognition. Microsoft.Speech.Recognition uses a different engine.