# Does the MS Speech Platform 11 Recognizer support ARPA compiled grammars?

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi, microsoft-speech-platform

How can I use ARPA files with MS Speech? The documentation for the Microsoft Speech Platform 11 Recognizer implies that one can compile a grammar from an ARPA file.

I am able to compile an ARPA file -- for instance, the tiny example [provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh378460(v%3doffice.14)) -- using the following command line:

```
CompileGrammar.exe -In stock.arpa -InFormat ARPA
```

I'm able to use the resulting CFG file in the following test:

```
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

// ...

using (var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US")))
{
    engine.LoadGrammar(new Grammar("stock.cfg"));
    var result = engine.EmulateRecognize("will stock go up");
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

This test passes, but note that it uses `EmulateRecognize()`.  When I switch to using an actual audio file, like this:

```
using (var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US"))) 
{
    engine.LoadGrammar(new Grammar("stock.cfg"));
    engine.SetInputToWaveFile("go-up.wav");
    var result = engine.Recognize();
}
```

**result** is always null and the test fails.

Microsoft [states quite clearly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh362862(v=office.14)) that it's supported, yet even very simple examples don't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a working recognizer using SRGS format?   There are a number of nitpicky details that you can get wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different answers to this question depending on which version of the Microsoft Speech SDK you're using. (See: [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2977338/222481)
)

### System.Speech (Desktop Version)

In this case, see [seiya1223's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540670/222481).  The sample code there works great.

### Microsoft.Speech (Server Version)

Perhaps because the server version does not include the "dictation engine," the Microsoft.Speech library will apparently never *match* an ARPA-sourced CFG.  However, it will still *hypothesize* what was said via the `SpeechRecognitionRejected` event.  Here are the necessary changes from seiya1223's desktop code:

1. Change your using statement from System.Speech to Microsoft.Speech, of course.
2. Add an event handler for the `SpeechRecognitionRejected` event.
3. In your event handler, examine the `e.Result.Text` property for the final hypothesis.

The following snippet should help illustrate:

```
static string transcription;

static void Main(string[] args)  
{
  using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-us")))
  {
    engine.SpeechRecognitionRejected += SpeechRecognitionRejectedHandler;
    // ...
  }
}

void SpeechRecognitionRejectedHandler(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result.Text))
    transcription = e.Result.Text;
}
```

This handler is called once at the end of recognition.  For example, here is the output from seiya1223's code, but using all of the available event handlers and a bunch of extra logging (emphasis mine):

> Starting asynchronous recognition...
>    In SpeechDetectedHandler:
>    - AudioPosition = 00:00:01.2300000
>    In SpeechHypothesizedHandler:
>    - Grammar Name = Stock; Result Text = Go
>    In SpeechHypothesizedHandler:
>    - Grammar Name = Stock; Result Text = will
>    In SpeechHypothesizedHandler:
>    - Grammar Name = Stock; Result Text = will Stock
>    In SpeechHypothesizedHandler:
>    - Grammar Name = Stock; Result Text = will Stock Go
>    In SpeechHypothesizedHandler:
>    - Grammar Name = Stock; Result Text = will Stock Go Up
>    **In SpeechRecognitionRejectedHandler:
>
>    - Grammar Name = Stock; Result Text = will Stock Go Up**
>    In RecognizeCompletedHandler.
>    - AudioPosition = 00:00:03.2000000; InputStreamEnded = True
>    - No result.
>   Done.

Answer (score 3):

For your question：

> Does the MS Speech Platform 11 Recognizer support ARPA compiled
>   grammars?

The answer is Yes.

Worked code on my side，just change the three properties: **Culture/Grammar/WaveFile**. I am not know your full code, but based on my test and the demo code, I guess the root cause is  we need handle the **SpeechRecognized** in our side, which you maybe have not done on your side.

```
static bool completed;

        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {
            // Initialize an in-process speech recognition engine.  
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
               new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-us")))
            {

                // Create and load a grammar.   
                Grammar dictation = new Grammar("stock.cfg");
                dictation.Name = "Dictation Grammar";

                recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictation);

                // Configure the input to the recognizer.  
                recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile("test.wav");

                // Attach event handlers for the results of recognition.  
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
                recognizer.RecognizeCompleted +=
                  new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(recognizer_RecognizeCompleted);

                // Perform recognition on the entire file.  
                Console.WriteLine("Starting asynchronous recognition...");
                completed = false;
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

                // Keep the console window open.  
                while (!completed)
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.  
        static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Text != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Recognized text =  {0}", e.Result.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Recognized text not available.");
            }
        }

        // Handle the RecognizeCompleted event.  
        static void recognizer_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error encountered, {0}: {1}",
                e.Error.GetType().Name, e.Error.Message);
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Operation cancelled.");
            }
            if (e.InputStreamEnded)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  End of stream encountered.");
            }
            completed = true;
        }
```

[image]
[image]

And the content of the wav is just "**will stock go up**"(The duration is about 2 seconds).

> For more infomation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Speech_Recognition_SpeechRecognitionEngine_SetInputToWaveFile_System_String_